# Get text value of a watermark bound textbox from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit, watermark

I want to get the text value of a textbox from javascript. The textbox has a watermark extender attached to it. So while taking the value from javascript, if the textbox is empty then also we are getting that water marktext.

Our markup is like

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server" MaxLength="30"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="wmname" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtname"
                                WatermarkText="Name" WatermarkCssClass="txt">
                            </asp:TextBoxWatermarkExtender>
```

JS:

```
$('input').blur(function() {            
        alert($(this).val());
    });
```

On the blur event if we didn't enter any value , then also its alerting "Name".

Is there any way to get the exact text of textbox ie not the watermark text from javacript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `wrapper behavior`, there is a property **_isWatermarked** that we can use to check whether the TextBox is watermarked.

Script:

```
<script>
function addValue() {
    if (!AjaxControlToolkit.TextBoxWrapper.get_Wrapper($get("TextBox1"))._isWatermarked) {
         $get("TextBox1").value = $get("TextBox1").value + ": Hello!";
     }
   }    
</script>
```

Controls:

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <cc1:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="TWE1" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox1"
 WatermarkText="Type here:" WatermarkCssClass="watermarked" />
```

Comment: but now i upgraded AjaxToolKit version to 3.5.51116.0 .. Now i am getting a script error "AjaxControlToolKit" is undefined. Do you know the reason?

Comment: have you included declarative at the top of the page something with "CC1" or "asp" or "Ajaxcontroltoolkit" and add scriptmanager below your opening form tag.

Comment: when i used something like this "Sys.Extended.UI.TextBoxWrapper.get_Wrapper($get(this.id))._isWatermarked)", it got worked...

Comment: I found the solution to your problem which is related here http://forums.asp.net/t/1069764.aspx/1

Comment: i didn't understand that.. The solution i mentioned above worked for me.. Do you know what actually it means..?

Comment: That is just an instance of the Sys.Extended.UI.TextBoxWrapper class for textbox control

Comment: JavaScript classes in the AjaxControlToolkit has been moved into Sys.Extended.UI and some of them renamed